# get the sorted date in vb

Tags: vb.net, sorting

i am writing simple program to get the sorted date . But it does not work.

```
Dim filepath As String = FileStr
Dim directoryPath As String =      System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
for Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
Dates = {
Date.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
        }.ToList
Next
Dates.Sort()
ComboBox1.DataSource = Dates
```

It only show one date ..where there are more than 10 date. and also the loop is working

I declare the List as global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the content of your list in every loop

```
Dim filepath As String = FileStr
Dim directoryPath As String =      System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
for Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
    Dates.Add(Date.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)))
Next
Dates.Sort(AddressOf SortDate)
ComboBox1.DataSource = Dates
```

---

UPDATE: Sorting issue

Then as a seperate function add:

```
Function SortDate(ByVal a As DateTime, ByVal b As DateTime) 
    Dim result As Integer = a.Year.CompareTo(b.Year) 
    If result = 0 Then 
        a.Month.CompareTo(b.Month) 
        If result = 0 Then 
            a.Day.CompareTo(b.Day) 
        End If 
    End If 
    Return result 
End Function
```

Comment: whats the issue? as long as the `Dates` list is initialized, it will work

Comment: if i put a msgbox(file) it shows one value ,then output as no result

Comment: put a breakpoint before the loop, and see if the `Dates` is being populated or not

Comment: the Date is not coming

Comment: please explain better... is this working: `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)`; can it be parsed: `Date.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))`; is the `Dates` count growing after every `Dates.Add(Date.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)))`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81598/discussion-between-keith-mifsud-and-satyajit).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop replaced the value of `Dates` each time, so you get only one date.

Change the loop like this:

```
Dates = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
    .Select(Function(file) Date.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)))
    .ToList
```

Comment: it shows value of 1 dimensional array of string can not converted to list